# How I can I delete sprites without obstructing the physics in SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, performance, sprite-kit, game-physics

I want to make a game in which sprites fall from the sky and stack up on the floor, however when there is a lot of layers the camera will move up so you can continue playing. After a while more and more rows of sprites will become invisible as the camera moves up. I want to delete these unused sprite-nodes to keep the performance as good as possible. But when I delete the nodes at the bottom of the stack, won't the entire thing collapse? Or should I detect when the bottom row is unused and then turn off physics for the row above it so it wont fall down and won't affect the rows above it or something of that nature.

I haven't actually made any code yet, I just wanna have a good idea of what I'm doing before I start the wrong way.

Comment: Indeed the stack would collapse. You'll have to be clever here. First, turn all objects below the screen into static bodies (set dynamic=NO). Then determine which of the still-dynamic bodies are or have recently been in contact with any of the below-screen static bodies. Keep those static bodies that have been in contact with a dynamic body in the past one or two seconds, and assume the rest is safe to delete. The actual implementation will depend mostly on what your game's requirements are.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I had to do something like that, I just hoped there was an easier/better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I totally agree, you would really have to be clever about it. Well setting the background image coordinates and looping the background for a "continuous scroll effect" would be Step NO.1 Then using particle physics or actually rendering Nodes would be Step NO.2 The tricky part like you said would be getting the ones below the scene to be destroyed, but I think that if you try and set boundaries, and maybe an if statement that runs the destruction of the particles below the boundaries. So the particles fall down slowly pile up but as the scene scrolls upwards the particles will be destroyed when the their anchor point goes below the x,y boundaries you set and thus keeping those still visible in the scene alive... That would be my way of going about it.